# Layout corruption with ExtJs 4.1 and Chrome 25

Tags: google-chrome, layout, extjs

I have posted this on the sencha forums as a bug, but I figured getting it out on stack overflow could be advantageous:

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?257622-Serious-layout-Issue-with-ExtJs-4.1-and-Chrome-25&p=943170#post943170

and a screenshot of it in action can be seen here:

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?257508-Strange-behaviors-in-Chrome-25-with-Ext-4.1

**Basically**, with ExtJs 4.1, after upgrading to Chrome 25, our users are sporadically seeing layout failure in our application.

It usually is noticed by the window 'close' button appearing skewed on the left of a window instead of the right, and all the form fields displayed vertically.  Once it happens, every subsequent component that is rendered is all messed up.

Reverting to chrome 24, or using Firefox makes the problem dissipate.
The issue shows up in IE when running Chrome Frame 25.

We have disabled our custom CSS, and still seen the issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is very hard to help without having a testcase, or some example code. I've never seen a problem like this before by upgrading browser (I've seen this when upgraden from 4.0.x to 4.1). But you didn't upgrade ExtJS right?

Comment: Didn't upgrade extjs but the first link has a test case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amphro's answer does address the issue, but doesn't completely eradicate it.

**The only real solution I have found is to upgrade to ExtJs 4.2.**

I can still replicate the issue with ExtJs 4.1.2 in Chrome 26 as well.

Answer (score 1):

We were experiencing a similar issue with our Ext application. We finally narrowed it down to floating numbers in the height and width of panels. For example, if you have any code that looks like `panel.setWidth(v1 / v2)`, change it to `panel.setWidth(Math.round(v1 / v2))`. Hope that helps.

Comment: This does provide an easy way to replicate the issue, though our window that causes it to occur has no incidents of setWidth/Height and such.
ExtJs 4.2 addresses the issue it seems, with the rework of their layout code.